# Auto populate hidden form fields in modelform

Tags: django

So my model, form, and view are working mostly. View works and sending the email works. The "message" is saved but I cannot get the message_to and message_from to save. It is supposed to save the usernames. I can get everything to save, but cannot get the message saved to the database WITH the to and from usernames. I am trying to only have 1 field in the message. "Content". The to and from should be hidden and auto-populated. I appreciate any other set of eyes on this. Thank you.

'models.py'

```
    class Message(models.Model):
        message_content = models.TextField()
        message_to = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='message_to')
        message_from = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='message_from')
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
        unread = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

'forms.py'

```
    class MessageSellerForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Message
```

'views.py'

```
    def ad_detail(request, *args, **kwargs):
template_name = 'x_ads/ad_detail.html'
ad = get_object_or_404(Ad, pk=kwargs['pk'])

ad.increment_view_count()

if request.method == 'POST':
    message_form = MessageSellerForm(data=request.POST)

    message_form.message_from = request.user.username
    message_form.message_to = ad.creator.username

    if message_form.is_valid():

        subject = 'Message about your ad. ' + ad.title
        from_email = request.user.email
        to_email = ad.creator.email
        message = 'You have a message about one of your ads waiting for you!'
        send_mail(subject=subject, message=message, from_email=from_email,
                  recipient_list=[to_email], fail_silently=False)

        messages.success(request, your message has been sent.')

        message_form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

else:
    message_form = MessageSellerForm()

return render(request, template_name, {'ad': ad, 'message_form': message_form})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do there, but there are other ways that I think will be a bit easier.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

You could instead:

```
# create the django object in memory, but don't save to the database
message = message_form.save(commit=False)
message.message_from = request.user.username
message.message_to = ad.creator.username
# now save it to the database
message.save()
```

If you do that you won't need the assignments to the message form further up:

```
message_form.message_from = request.user.username
message_form.message_to = ad.creator.username
```

#### EDIT

You might also need to modify your `MessageSellerForm` to not include the `message_from` and `message_to` fields so that validation will work.  That's OK because you know that you'll be assigning the right values to those fields after form validation but before saving to the database.